# How to set correct format of DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

I would like to print DateTime in format `HH:mm:ss`. 
This is current code

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T");
```

this give me format:  `HH:mm:ss:fff`

I found that `CultureInfo` can help, so I transform code like

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T", new CultureInfo(fr-FR))
```

or

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T", new CultureInfo(hr-HR))
```

with no change. Can you help me?

Comment: You just answer it: `ToString("HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: @Ian In such a case, it would be better to escape `:` character as `':'` if OP's current culture does not use `:` as a `TimeSeparator`.

Comment: @SonerGönül you are right... not all cultures use `:` as `TimeSeparator`

Comment: @Ian Exactly. In .NET 4.5, there are 5 cultures use a different character than `:` for `TimeSeparator` but OP maybe_even_ created a custom culture himself for `CurrentCulture` setting, who knows..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The `"T"` Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#LongTime) uses [`LongTimePattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.longtimepattern) property of the culture settings you used. And this property changes over the culture settings.

For example; it can be `h:mm:ss tt`, `H:mm:ss` or `hh:mm:ss tt` etc..

But [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture) uses `HH:mm:ss` format which is exactly what you want. Just pass `InvariantCulture` as a second parameter in your `ToString` method and you will be fine.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or you can use [custom date and time formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) like;

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

By the way, `fr-FR` culture *also* use `HH:mm:ss` as a `LongTimePattern` but `hr-HR` culture use `H:mm:ss` format.

Comment: It seemt that there I have another problem. I would like to subtract two DateTime - DateTime.Now and Variable of type DateTime. I have this code (DateTime.Now - Varible).ToString("T"); and this give me HH:mm:ss:fff. When I set ToString("HH:mm:ss"); it throws an error - Input string was not in a correct format. .... DateTime.Now.ToString("T", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); also dont working. Can you help?

Comment: @TomášČičman `DateTime.Now - Varible` returns a [`TimeSpan`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan), not a `DateTime`. It has a little bit different formatting than `DateTime`. In such a case, you can use `(DateTime.Now - Varible).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` for example. Take a look at [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) timespan formatting.